# install MongoDB on XAMPP

Tags: mongodb, xampp

```
PHP Version 5.3.8
```

and `php_mongo-1.3.1` 
i added this file `php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll`  to

```
 xampp/php/ext
```

, i made a copy from it , i changed the name to  `php_mongo.dll`

and i added this to `php.ini`
`extension=php_mongo.dll`  before

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

when i restart the computer and open it again Apache doesn't run

after that i used `php_mongo-1.4.0` 
i added `php_mongo-1.4.0-5.4-vc9.dll`

and i added this to  `php.ini`
`extension=php_mongo-1.4.0-5.4-vc9.dll`

but this msg appeared "xampp unable to load dynamic library php_mongo-1.4.0-5.4-vc9.dll"

what can i do ??

Comment: Have you looked at error logs of Apache?

Comment: [Mon Jun 08 13:58:27 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

Comment: [Mon Jun 08 14:03:08 2015] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Jun 08 14:03:08 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs on older versions of xampp. Update it to a later version.